# Update shell command history from within bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line

I use control-r on the command line frequently to search for previous commands but cannot get this to work for commands that have just been run in a bash script.

I've tried running the script directly and using 'source' but history shows no record.

Is there anyway to get history updated via a script?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `history -s command` to store the command in the history list.

Example:

```
$ history -s echo foo

[Ctrl+R]
(reverse-i-search)`foo': echo foo
```

Alternatively, write your commands to a file and then use `history -n file` to read commands from the file into the current history list.

Example:

```
$ echo "echo bar" > /tmp/file
$ history -n /tmp/file

[Ctrl+R]
(reverse-i-search)`bar': echo bar
```

Comment: The latter use case is the one I'm after but unfortunately does not work for me. I'm on a Mac... Hmm..